# Get value of selected RadioButton in asp.net mvc

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc

```
<td>
  @if (ViewBag.MyList as System.Collections.IEnumerable != null)
  {
    int i = 1;
    foreach (var m in new  SelectList(ViewBag.MyList as System.Collections.IEnumerable, "Value", "Text", 0))
    {
      @Html.RadioButton("MyList" + i, m.value)
      @Html.Label(m.Text)
      i += 1;
    }
  }
</td>
```

If i have code similar to the above in an ASP.NET MVC view, how do I get the value of the selected RadioButton in jQuery? Some thing along the line `$.trim($("#MyList").val())` doesn't seem right as #MyList (i.e name of the drop-down will be dynamic depending on the value of variable i)

Comment: Why on earth are you creating a `SelectList` (particularly when you don't even use it or any of its properties)? And why create individual radio buttons where you can select  any or all of them (radio buttons should be grouped to allow selection of one from a group). And since the value of all your radio buttons is "IdValue", what the point? I assume your not understanding what your actually generating with this code.

Comment: Did you try any of the answers?

Comment: OK, Now makes a bit more sense :). `var selectedValue = $('input[type='radio']:checked');` but you need to delete the `i` bit - they should have the same name! (Note I'm assuming these are the only radio buttons - otherwise you would need to be more specific and add `[name="MyList"]` to the selector). But really, just `foreach (var m in ViewBag.MyList)`

Comment: Or do you actually want to be able to select more than one? - in which case they should be checkbox's, not radio buttons

Comment: @StephenMuecke, i want to select ONLY one and have one with a pre- known particular text selected by default.

Comment: In that case, the radio buttons must have the same name. And if you want to preselect one you need to bind to a property. Use a view model with (say) `List<string> Items` and `string SelectedItem` and use strongly typed helpers (using a `SelectList` does absolutely nothing)

Answer (score 1):

jQuery has "starts with" selector for such case. To get the selected item, use "checked":

```
var v = $.trim($("[id^='MyList']:checked").val());
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$("input[id^='MyList']:checked").val()
```